# Foreach in foreach login in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach

How can I make this logic work in powershell?

```
$i = ("SharePointCDPTestProject1_Feature1", "SharePointCDPTestProject1_Feature2", "SharePointCDPTestProject1_Feature3"); 
$a = Get-SPSite  http://localhost/sts*;
Foreach($id in $i)
{
    Foreach($p in $a)
    {
        Enable-SPFeature –identity $id -URL $p
    }
}
```

Sorry.. I'm noob in ps

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = ("SharePointCDPTestProject1_Feature1", "SharePointCDPTestProject1_Feature2", "SharePointCDPTestProject1_Feature3"); 
$a = Get-SPSite  http://localhost/sts*;
$i | Foreach{
    #save current id
    $id=$_
    $a | Foreach{
        Enable-SPFeature –identity $id -URL $_
    }
}
```

Comment: ForEach-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'Process'. Cannot convert the "{" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Mana
gement.Automation.ScriptBlock".
At line:1 char:13
+ $i | Foreach <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ForEach-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand

Comment: $i = ("SharePointCDPTestProject1_Feature1", "SharePointCDPTestProject1_Feature2", "SharePointCDPTestProject1_Feature3");
$a =  Get-SPWebApplication "http://localhost" | Get-SPSite -Limit All | Get-SPWeb -Limit ALL

Foreach($id in $i)
{
 Foreach($p in $a)
 {
  Enable-SPFeature –identity $id -URL $p.Url
 }
}

worked for me